Proof of time dilation
I'm trying to wrap my head around special relativity and why it proves time dilation. I understand the derivation of its' kinematics, but the kinematics only proves clock dilation, that is, only the clock runs slower, but not time it self. As an example, if I board a ship traveling near speed of light for 10 years, when I return, the onboard atomic clock will not register 10 years, but I will still be 10 years older.
It is only when we assume that speed of light is constant in all reference frames, then we can only explain it by time dilation and / or length contraction, that in my example, everyone on earth will be dead, but I will be 10 years older.
However, I am unable to find experiments that prove speed of light is constant in all reference frames (only that "ether" does not exist), and I can only find experiments that support time dilation, which involves extended half-life of unstable particles traveling at near light speeds. However, the extended half-life can be explained by many other hypothesises other than time dilation, for example higher total relativistic energy result in higher half-life.
Is there any other experiments that prove spped of light is constant in all reference frames, or experiments that support time dilation (not just "clock-dilation")?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_testing_of_time_dilation

I have nice question to you,- What do clocks measure ? (since according to you they can't measure time) ?

"the extended half-life can be explained by many other hypothesises": well, no. And what does "higher total relativistic energy result in higher half-life" even mean?

If you did not age in step with the clock, you would be aware of this, and see the clock running in slow motion compared to your consciousness.  Thus, you would have a way to see locally that you are in a state of uniform motion with respect to some absolute frame, which violates the principle of relativity

Clocks does measure time, but having a clock run faster or slower doesn't modify the speed which time progresses. For example, my watch could run slightly faster or slower than the atomic clock that we use as reference, but that doesn't affect how time progresses in my frame of reference compared to other people's frame of reference.
Why can't extended half-life be explained by other hypothesises? Is the only way to explain extended half-life that the muon is experiencing time dilation?

This question would really benefit from some paragraphs and organization.

Much better, thanks!

" Why can't extended half-life be explained by other hypothesises?" Well of course, in principle, it could. But I am not aware of any single such alternate hypothesis. AFAIK extended half-life is only explained by time dilation, which makes it a wonderful illustration of relativity.

Well now there's an alternate hypothesis that is completely plausible based on my current understanding of modern-physics experiments :D

Except that you did not say what "higher total relativistic energy result in higher half-life" actually means.

It is my hypothesis (or I'm sure other's hypothesized this as well), that if an unstable particle has higher total relativistic energy (energy from rest mass + energy from momentum), it could result in it decaying at a lower rate. This hypothesis could explain, why unstable particles traveling at near light speeds, experience longer half-lifes compared to the same particles at rest. (Since at near light speeds, the particles have higher momentum / energy)

"It is my hypothesis" - end of story.

It is my hypothesis… Personal theories and non-mainstream physics are off-topic on this site.


if I board a ship traveling near speed of light for 10 years, when I
return, the onboard atomic clock will not register 10 years, but I
will still be 10 years older.

Huh? You and the atomic clock are subject to the same laws of physics since you are in the same reference frame. You will have aged exactly as much as the atomic clock says time has elapsed.
The internal processes that govern how a clock ticks are subject to governance by the speed of light just like the processes that contribute to biological aging, thought/consciousness, etc.

Well, the problem here is that you are missing one of the fundamental pillars of special relativity. That is, the principle of relativity.
The principle of relativity states that the laws of physics must be the same in all (inertial) reference frames and is usually accompanied by the hypothesis that there is no preferred inertial reference frame. If what you suggest were to be true, that is, that when you move a clock to relativistic speeds, it is not time itself that changes but the clock that gets delayed. This would imply the existence of a preferred reference frame (the one in which clocks don't get delayed).
Thus, since there is no preferred reference frame, clocks running slower (as long as the clocks work properly) is equivalent to time itself running slower.
The same applies to your example of muon decay, but it is even worse; if you assume that the half-life depends on the energy (which is frame dependent), then you can only explain the observation if the laws of physics are frame dependent (again you violate the principle of relativity). This would be completely incompatible with thousands of experiments.

The principle of relativity is based on the assumption that speed of light is constant in all reference frames, correct. However what I'm asking is there any experiments that proves either speed of light is constant in all reference frames, OR, that time dilation occurs as speed approaches c (without other plausible explanations).

I don't think you need the constancy of the speed of light for anything. What I told you in my answer is that the combination of clock time dilation and the principle of relativity is enough to prove that time itself is the one being dilated. You seem to accept clock time dilation in your OP (and there is plenty of experimental evidence for that). Whether the time dilation is actually a consequence of the constancy of the speed of light (as physics says) or by other hypotheses is not really relevant to your question.

"[Are] there any other experiments that prove speed of light is constant in all reference frames, or experiments that support time dilation (not just "clock-dilation")?
(a) There's no limit to the number of experiments you'd have to do to prove that the speed of light is the same in ALL inertial frames of reference. So we take it as a hypothesis made plausible by experiments of the Michelson–Morley type, and made almost indisputable by the success of the predictions of the theory built upon it.
(b) How could you possibly test time dilation without measuring time? And any instrument or procedure for measuring time is, by definition, a clock. [Agnius Vasiliauskas has made this point.]
(c) "However, the extended half-life can be explained by many [hypotheses] other than time dilation[.]" No doubt so, but the simplicity of the time dilation explanation and its being one of a coherent set of predictions from the SR view of space-time make us need a very good reason to challenge it.

a) I've been reading into Michelson-Morley type experiments, doesn't it only prove that there is no medium which light waves propagate through, and that speed of light is constant in all directions?
But what it lacks in proving, is that speed of light is not constant in all inertial reference frames, that is, the observed speed of light in a spaceship traveling at near c, could be different from observed speed of light in a stationary frame of reference.

b) a clock can have different speeds, for example, I can have a 24 hr clock, and a clock that's twice as slow, a 12 hr clock, the 2 clock will be mismatched after running for the same amount of time, but that doesn't change the "time" as we understand it.

(a) At the time, I think that 'no medium' was considered by many to be the main conclusion, but in fact this is  a somewhat indirect inference: the experiment simply shows that the speed of light seems to be the same in inertial frames moving relative to each other.

I challenge that understanding. This experiment is only performed on 1 frame of reference (Earth), and shows that light traveling in perpendicular directions at the exact same speed. However, it doesn't show that if we perform the exact same experiment at different speeds / frame of reference, that the light will not be traveling at a different speed (it will still travel at the same speed in perpendicular directions in the new frame of reference though).

I challenge that understanding. This experiment is only performed on 1 frame of reference (Earth), and shows that light traveling in perpendicular directions at the exact same speed. However, it doesn't show that if we perform the exact same experiment at different speeds / frame of reference, that the light will still travel at the same speed compared to speed in the Earth's frame of reference (it will still travel at the same speed in perpendicular directions in the new frame of reference though).

@ZhuMengxi There are no "proofs" in physics. We build models that fit the experimental data that we have. Naturally, those are always subject to future refutation, by experiments that tell us something we didn't know before. You can "challenge" any understanding you like, but ultimately, such challenge must point to experimental data that gives reason to question the current model. There are endless ways to speculate along the lines of: "Maybe if we do X, the prediction Y by the model won't hold", but just speculating this way isn't really a "challenge" to the prevailing models/theories.

"I challenge that understanding" - really?

I challenge that understanding. Personal theories and non-mainstream physics are off-topic on this site.


Is there any other experiments that prove spped of light is constant in all reference frames,

There are a wide variety of experiments which show that the two-way speed of light is a constant in any inertial reference frame.
The Michelson-Morley in 1887 is widely regarded as one of the first experiments to show this, although the experiment wasn't actually intended to show this. At the time, the experiment was designed to detect the motion of the Earth relative to the "aether", the wave medium through which light was hypothesised to travel. The absence of any detectable motion was a surprise at the time.
There is no known experiment which shows the one-way speed of light to be constant (that is, isotropic), as this is not thought to be independently measurable.

or experiments that support time dilation (not just "clock-dilation")?

As the passage of time is not measurable independently from the progression of clocks, there is no known experiment capable of distinguishing the two cases.
The exact physical nature of the passage of time and how it is measured, is in my experience a fuzzy theoretical subject. You will sometimes hear atomic clocks described as "constant" by physicists, when in fact the experimental evidence is quite consistent with them being variable under spatial translation.
What is clear from experimentation is that dilation affects all known types of clock, including any local physical process capable of being used for a timekeeping purpose.
